# How to use logic controller with an array in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I've a CSV with list of values that are passed in via each POST request and I would like to store a response attribute eg. response_some_id, that generated for each unique POST request.

Once I obtain the array for that set, I would like to run the GET requests on that array; please let me know if I need more details that could help.

[image: jmeter]

Comment: For each POST, do you expect an array of response attribute?

Comment: There is one single POST request in the test but 'no of threads' is set to 5, iterating over the CSV making 5 simultaneous POSTs to get 5 different responses and hence 5 different `response_some_id`. The objective is to store them in an array and then iterate GET requests on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of your "Post Call"
2. Add the code into the Post Processor's "Script" area

   ```
   vars.put("response_some_id_" + ${__counter(TRUE,)}, "foo");
   ```

   The code above will generate following JMeter Variables:

   ```
   response_some_id1=foo
   response_some_id2=foo
   response_some_id3=foo
   response_some_id4=foo
   response_some_id5=foo
   ```

   If you have "response_some_id" variable you can substitute `"foo"` bit with `vars.get("response_some_id")`
3. Change your Loop Controller to [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller). Configure the ForEach Controller as follows:

   - Input Variable Prefix: `response_some_id`
   - Start Index: `0`
   - End Index: how many IDs do you have. You can leave this blank.
   - Output Variable Name: anything meaningful, it will hold current "response_some_id_N" value. I.e. `current_response_id`
   - Leave `Add "_" before the number` ticked
4. Use `${current_response_id}` in your "Get Call"

Reference material:

- [Documentation entry for __counter function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter)
- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)